# How to activate broadcast receiver when call comes and cut the call using ITelephony?

Tags: android

I am using the hidden APIs of the Android SDK in my code (i.e.`ITelephony`), but my broadcast receiver class is not getting active when a call comes. Because of that, my call is not getting ended.

I have used broadcast receiver inside an activity because I want to use context of an activity for some displaying purpose. I do not get where the problem is! Please help.

```
 package com.example.callprio;

 import java.lang.reflect.Method;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ActivityManager;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.IntentFilter;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.ContactsContract;
 import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
 import android.telephony.SmsManager;
 import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony; 

 public class MyCallBroadcastReceiver extends Activity

 {
private static final boolean USE_ITELEPHONY = true;

/**
    * AIDL access to the telephony service process
    */
    private ITelephony telephonyService;  
  
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver()
    {

     private String id;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    
     MyPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

    telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     phone_number = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
    System.out.println("Phone Number : " + phone_number);
    Log.i("phone_number", phone_number);
    
    
    Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, phone_number);

    // Query the table
    Cursor phoneCursor = MyCallBroadcastReceiver.this.getContentResolver().query(
            myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);

    // Get the phone numbers from the contact
    for (phoneCursor.moveToFirst(); !phoneCursor.isAfterLast();                
phoneCursor.moveToNext())
    {
   // Get a phone number id
        id = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

        Log.i("Contact_id", id);
    //    sb.append("Phone: " + phoneNumber + "\n");
    }       
    
    connectToTelephonyService();
    
    Log.i("After connectToTelephonyService()", "Telephony service connected");
          
    fetchPrioById(id);
}
};



private TelephonyManager telephony;


private MyPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener;

private String phone_number;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
super.onPause();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
}


/** 
 * get an instance of ITelephony to talk handle calls with 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") private void connectToTelephonyService() {
    try 
    {
    // "cheat" with Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's ITelephony 
            Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(telephony);

    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         Log.e("TAG",
                 "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
         Log.e("TAG", "Exception object: " + e);
        finish();
    }               
}

protected void fetchPrioById(String id) {

int prio=0;

int cid=Integer.parseInt(id);
 String query="SELECT priority FROM Call WHERE contact_id="+cid;
 
  DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
  databaseAdapter.open();
 
 Cursor cursor=null;
 
  cursor= databaseAdapter.getSQLiteDatabase().rawQuery(query,null);
 
  if (cursor != null)
     {
      //that means priority is assigned take prio from table
      if (cursor.moveToFirst())
         {
       prio = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("priority"));  
         }
     }
  
  if(prio==0)
  {
      ignoreCall();
  }
  else if(prio==1)
  {
      onSilent(); 
  }
  else if(prio==3)
  {
     sendMessage();
  }

  else if (cursor == null)
  {
      //means priority is not assigned so default behaviour i.e. lower prio
   ignoreCall();      
  }
  
  cursor.close();
  databaseAdapter.open();
 
}//FetchFunc

private void sendMessage() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ignoreCall();
String message="I am in meeting,Call you later";
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone_number, null, message, null, null);
}

private void onSilent() {
telephonyService.silenceRinger();
}

private void ignoreCall() {
if (USE_ITELEPHONY)
        ignoreCallAidl();
else
        ignoreCallPackageRestart();
}

 /**
  * package restart technique for ignoring calls 
   */
 private void ignoreCallPackageRestart() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    am.restartPackage("com.android.providers.telephony");
    am.restartPackage("com.android.phone");
 }

/** 
  * AIDL/ITelephony technique for ignoring calls
 */
 private void ignoreCallAidl() {
    try 
    {
            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.endCall();
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("EXCEPTION","FATAL ERROR: call to service method endCall failed.");
            Log.e("TAG", "Exception object: " + e);
    }
}       

}//class Activity ends here
```